# WordPress Plugins repo, get stable tag

Tags: svn, wordpress, svn-externals

I have a local SVN server running on my machine. In it I have a repository containing some default `/wp-content` stuff, that I use for every project(default plugins, default theme framework, etc). Today I just remembered that instead of having each plugin's files in my repo, I can use `svn:externals` to fetch the latest files of each plugin.

That's good, but there is one problem - not all plugins' stable tag is `/trunk` - so I would possibly end-up with a development version(that is in `/trunk`), instead of the `stable` version, specified by the `stable` tag in the `readme.txt`.

So my question is - is there a way to get the `stable` tag, whatever it is, using `svn:externals`(or anything else anyway - when I think about it now, I might be able to run a shell script that will check each of the plugin's `stable` tag and update the repo accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins hosted at WordPress.org need to have a file called `readme.txt` that's formatted in a particular way.  See this:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt

One of the tags near the top of readme.txt is `Stable tag:`.

When a Wordpress.org blog administrator goes to download a plugin, wordpress.org looks in svn at trunk/readme.txt, grabs the stable tag, then gets the plugin from tags/*stable-tag*/

So developers releasing updates need to create a new stable tag, then change the readme.txt and check it into the trunk.

I don't know if you can pull off this behavior with svn:externals.  But it's worth a try.

Comment: I feared that checking the `readme.txt` might be the only way to do this :) If nothing else pops-up, I'll figure-out a shell script that will update my repo with the proper `svn:externals` sources. I might as well ask on the WordPress.org forums to see if anyone else has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/nikdow/wordpress_plugins/ for python script to update plugins and themes from Wordpress SVN repository.  We use it so that the server root cron gets updates twice a day, and we set file permissions so that the webserver cannot update directories with PHP files.  This fixes the most common path to wordpress hacking.   We also set PHP so it won't execute anything in the uploads directory.